# AppEngine standard and Memorystore connection issue

Tags: spring-boot, redis, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-memorystore

I have Memorystore instance:

```
gcloud redis instances list --region europe-west1
INSTANCE_NAME      VERSION    REGION        TIER   SIZE_GB  HOST      PORT  NETWORK  RESERVED_IP  STATUS  CREATE_TIME
sm-cache  REDIS_4_0  europe-west1  BASIC  1        10.1.1.3  6379  default  10.1.1.0/28  READY   2019-05-30T19:03:29
```

and App Engine standard application running in same region.

There is VPC required to connect. I tried adding it without lack. What should be CIDR for such connection? Same as for Memorystore does not work:

```
gcloud beta compute networks vpc-access connectors describe sm-01-vpc --region europe-west1 
ipCidrRange: 10.1.1.0/28
maxThroughput: 1000
minThroughput: 200
name: projects/salesmanago-data-01/locations/europe-west1/connectors/sm-01-vpc
network: default
state: ERROR
```

What IP I should use in Spring Boot configuration? Any suggestions? This is not clearly described in docs and tutorials.

So far I am getting error in application:

```
Unable to connect to Redis; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to 10.1.1.3:6379
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What should be CIDR for such connection? Same as for Memorystore does not work:

Use the ip range does not exist in your VPC network and different from the one memorystore uses.

> What IP I should use in Spring Boot configuration

The IP showed in `gcloud redis instances list --region europe-west1`

BTW Serverless seems only work on us-central1 as of now, not sure if it works on europe-west1

Comment: We have tried this as well. I asked Google support if this is available in europe-west1. You can create VCP there - but only with gcloud command line tool.

Comment: @Konrad I see, nevertheless, you should choose a different IP range.

Comment: Yes, you are right. As confirmed by Google support, Serverless VPC are not fully supported in europe-west1 especially where it comes to Peering.
The solution is to use flex environment.